# BERT model after sequintial get error TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_ids'

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

Hellow!

I have pretrained BERT model with my head.

I want to cut with head and use uotputs of with last layers (-6 index) concatenate with ather model output in new class.

```
model_d = torch.load(f'{conf.save_path}/DeepPavlov/rubert-base-cased_2.pt', map_location=device)
newmodel_bert = torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(model_d.modules())[:-6]))
```

But now forward of new model get error:

```
newmodel_bert.forward(input_ids = next(iter(train_data_loader))['input_ids'], attention_mask = next(iter(train_data_loader))['attention_mask'])
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 newmodel_bert.forward(input_ids = next(iter(train_data_loader))['input_ids'], attention_mask = next(iter(train_data_loader))['attention_mask'])
> TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_ids'

First model get forward norm without errors

What happend with model after seq?

```
# model_d
    class Bert(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Bert, self).__init__()
            self.bert = bert_model # from Hugginface
            self.drop = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
           # such layers for head
    
        def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
            
            outputs = self.bert(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
           # MyHead
            return output
```

Comment: How was `model_d` defined?

Comment: add answer to topic

Comment: How was `bert_model` defined?